# ASP.NET MVC - Mapping more than one query string parameter to a pretty url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, query-string

I am a bit stuck on the design of my seo friendly urls for mvc....Take for example the following url:
http://myapp/venues/resturants.aspx?location=central&orderBy=top-rated

With my mvc app i have mapped it as follows:
http://myapp/venues/list/resturants/central/top-rated
{controller}/{action}/{category}/{location}/{order}

Now the only problem is that location and order are optional...so it should be possible to submit a request like: http://myapp/venues/list/resturants/top-rated .  This proves to be a problem when the request hits the controller action, the location parameter has picked up "top-rated", naturally.

Any suggestions?  I' am  considering using explicit querystrings to handle more than one parameter but this is really my last option as i dont want to sacrifice SEO too much.

Has anyone eles run into such dilemmas? And how did you handle it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the allowed values for location and order are unique (i.e. when they come in, you can tell them apart, or else if they only supply one, how are you going to know if it's a location or an order?), then you could just take two parameters and work out what they are in the controller.

Route: `{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}`

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string param1, string param2)
{
    string location;
    string order;
    if (!ParseLocation(param1, out location))
    { ParseLocation(param2, out location); }
    // ...
}
```

Not particularly elegant, but does let you have the URLs you want.

Comment: yep, was exploring this method. I guess i was kinda hoping someone has done something clever with the RouteBase class or something special with the routetables....Thanks alot!

Answer (score 14):

Click on your [profile link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52065/wololo) and look at the URLs for Stats, Recent, Response, etc.

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/52065?sort=recent#sort-top
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/52065?sort=stats#sort-top

with no sort it defaults to stats

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/52065

**Optional paramters should be query parameters**

Answer (score 2):

You will always have this issue if you have multiple optional parameters.  Either make one or both of them non-optional (and positioned earlier in the query string than the optional one) or use the querystring parameter notation.

Answer (score 2):

ok guys just posting a solution i've been playing with so far.

I have set up my routes using constraints as follows:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "VenuesList",                                              
            "venues/list/{category}/{location}/{orderBy}",             
            new { controller = "venues", action = "list", category = "", location = "", orderBy = "" },
            new { location = "central|east|west|south", orderBy = "top-rated|price" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
            "VenuesListByLocation",                                              
            "venues/list/{category}/{location}",                           
            new { controller = "venues", action = "list", category = "", location = "" },
            new { location = "central|east|west|south" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "VenuesListByOrder",                                              
            "venues/list/{category}/{orderBy}",                           
            new { controller = "venues", action = "list", category = "", orderBy = "" },
            new { orderBy = "top-rated|price" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "VenuesListDefault",                                              
            "venues/list/{category}",                           
            new { controller = "venues", action = "list", category = "" }

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The idea is that if the validation fails it will go to the next route in the list...eventually hitting the default.

Needs some more testing but has worked well so far...

Comment: this is certainly possible, but not a very maintainable long term solution.  I'd look into {*pathInfo} as a catchall route parameter and then do the parsing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a property in the page for each possible querystring parameter?

This way you can handle it any way you choose with just a few lines of code...