# ASP.net MVC - Use Model Binder without query string values or fancy routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, model, modelbinders, model-binding

I have an **Asp.net MVC** app that currently works well using the default model binder and urls with complex parameters like this:

**example.com/Controller/Action?a=hello&b=world&c=1&d=2&e=3**  (notice the question mark)

The different urls automatically map to Action Method parameters using the built in model binder.  I would like to continue using the standard model binder but I need to get rid of the query string.  We want to put these urls behind a [CDN that does not support resources that vary by query strings (Amazon Cloud front)](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/07/enhanced-cloudfront-logs-now-with-query-strings.html) so we need to remove the question mark from our urls and do something silly like this

**example.com/Controller/Action/a=hello&b=world&c=1&d=2&e=3**  (no question mark)

These urls are only used via AJAX, so I'm not interested in making them user or SEO friendly.  I want to just drop the question mark and keep all my code exactly the same. The hitch is, I'm unsure about how to keep using the MVC model binder and abandoning it would be a lot of work.

I don't want to use a complex route to map my objects [like this question did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417000/asp-net-mvc-mapping-more-than-one-query-string-parameter-to-a-pretty-url/420335#420335) and, instead, I am planning to use a single simple route like the one below

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "NoQueryString",                    // Route name
        "NoQueryString/{action}/{query}", // 'query' = querystring without the ?
        new {
            controller = "NoQueryString",
            action = "Index",
            query = "" }  // want to parse with model binder - By NOT ROUTE
    );
```

**Option 1 (preferred): OnActionExecuting**
I plan to use the catchall "query" value in the route above to inject the old query string into the default model binder before the Controller Actions execute using the OnActionExecuting method in my controller.  However, I'm a bit unsure if I can just add back the question mark.   *Can I do this? How would you recommend modifying the url?*

**Option 2: Custom Model Binder**
I also could make some sort of Custom Model Binder that just tells the default model binder to treat the "query" value like a query string.  *Would you prefer this method? Can you point me to a relevant example?*

I am a bit worried that this is an edge case and would love some input before I start trying to implement Option 1 or Option 2 and stumble onto unforseen bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a custom value provider with a catchall route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NoQueryString",
    "NoQueryString/{controller}/{action}/{*catch-em-all}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

and the value provider:

```
public class MyCustomProvider : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var value = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["catch-em-all"] as string;
        var backingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(value);
            foreach (string key in nvc)
            {
                backingStore.Add(key, nvc[key]);
            }
        }
        return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(
            backingStore, 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        );
    }
}
```

which you register in `Application_Start`:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new MyCustomProvider());
```

and now all that's left is a model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then navigate to: `NoQueryString/Home/Index/a=hello&b=world&c=1&d=2&e=3`. The `Index` is hit and the model is bound.

Remark: Notice the `ValidateInput(false)` on the controller action. That's probably gonna be needed because ASP.NET won't allow you to use special characters such as `&` as part of a URI. You might also need to tweak your web.config a little:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

For more information about those tweaks make sure you have read Scott Hansleman's [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).

Comment: The request validation bit has me a little spooked about bugs.  Would I need that if I just added the question mark back at the controller level rather than at application start?

Comment: I guess I could encode whole query string, but it would be nice to avoid double encoding since the values are already encoded.

Comment: @Glenn, I don't understand your question. The validation part is important because otherwise ASP.NET will throw an exception saying that you have tried to send dangerous characters as part of your route. Normally the `&` character should be used only in the query string which is not your case and you need to circumvent it if you ever wanted to support urls as this one.

Comment: Sorry, you caught me pre-coffee. Is it possible to modify the urls before validation kicks in?   Basically, I would just add back the ? so that the "query" becomes a normal query string again.  Now that I think about it, the check for unsafe url validation is probably way before my controller.. maybe even before "Application.Begin Request".  If that is the case, I would prefer not to turn off Request Validation because it has security risks right?  So, then the "query" part of my inbound urls would need to be encoded to use 'safe' characters and then I could decode them after validation.

Comment: @Glen, no modifying the query string is not possible.

Comment: Great detail on your example by the way.  I'm going to test it out today and see how it does.  One more quick question. So you're sure I can't just intercept the url in global.asax at  Application_BeginRequest() and add back the "?" at that point in the pipeline?

Comment: @Glenn this is me assuming but I'd really think you would need to do that at the IIS level, prior to ASP.NET. That you could either it do it with an IIS rewrite rule or an actual IIS extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using the method above with the value mapper.  So far it is working perfectly under load. I think an IIS method might be a little faster.  We are preparing a top to bottom performance review and I will add your IIS idea to the items to test.

Answer (score 2):

Whats the problem with "complex" routing definitions?  The routes the question you linked to are very very simple. Defaults can go a long way.  Better to use the default capabilities of MVC to turn:

```
example.com/Controller/Action/a=hello&b=world&c=1&d=2&e=3
```

into

```
example.com/Controller/Action/hello/world/1/2/3
```

than start re-wiring core bits like RouteValue handling ( option 1 ) or implementing a custom model binder.

I know this doesn't answer your question but it seems like you made a choice about not using MVC's routing capabilities without understanding the technical ramifications.  You know what they say "good friends stop each other from doing stupid things".

Comment: I have over a dozen routes, each with multiple values. To use your method I would have to map hundreds of individual properties.  I think avoiding this labor is why the model binder exists.  The model binder allows route values to change just by changing the view model.  For example, if several of my Action Methods share a common ViewModel objects as one of their puts and also take different inputs, all I need is one route and one value provider.  Also, if I later need to add another property I can simply add the property to the shared view model object and I'm done.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  Sorry if I didn't adequately convey the complexity of the urls involved.  Mapping techniques like you described work well for simpler, user friendly urls... that's just not the situation here.

Comment: @Glenn - No problem.  From the other question you linked to it sounded like you had a small known amount of routes and not thousands of combinations.  Still even with a dozen routes I'd check out how to use defaults instead.  @Darin Dimitrov 's answer is really good, like it always is, but i'm not sure you need it.