# How to get parameter from url in mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an url which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:60480/game/<name_of_game/Comments
```

In my action method I want to get a name of game. I could do it with this:

```
string gameKey = HttpContext.Request.Url.Segments[2].Trim("//".ToCharArray());
```

But I suppose there are more elegant ways. Which ones?

Comment: What is your Action name? Did you define some custom route?

Comment: `model binding` does it better, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800881/asp-net-mvc-use-model-binder-without-query-string-values-or-fancy-routes)

Comment: @freshbm Yes, I defined a custom route. Action name: 'GetComment'